# Optimal C implementation of the Towers of Hanoi puzzle with k pegs

Tags: c, performance, towers-of-hanoi

How do you solve the Towers of Hanoi puzzle when there are k pegs?  Can it be done in an optimal way in C?  Is there a greedy algorithm for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this github page for the code in C: https://github.com/kcolford/hanoi/blob/master/src/hanoi.c

See this page to know why it's minimal: http://kcolford.com/the-towers-of-hanoi-2/